# Emacs, complete list of color "keys"

Tags: files, emacs, colors, init

If you want to customize the colors in Emacs, specifying them in the `.emacs` init file, without installing any extra package, and without using a pre-made theme, something like this seems to work:

```
(set-background-color "#003c3c")
(set-foreground-color "#ffffff")
(set-face-background 'fringe "#253c3c")
(set-face-background 'cursor "#ffffff")
(set-face-background 'region "#ff0000")
(set-face-foreground 'font-lock-comment-face "#ff0000")
(set-cursor-color "#00ff00")
```

But for doing this, it would be useful to have a complete list of all the "keys" for these "key-value" pairs. (I don't know if "key" is the right term in Emacs-lingo.. just getting started with Emacs)

Is such a complete list available anywhere? Or can I somehow generate one?

(I currently use the GNU OSX version of Emacs in its own window, not in a terminal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you type `M-x customize-face RET` and then hit TAB, the completion window will provide a list of all faces, and you could copy the list from the completion window.

Or you could hit RET, and then you would be brought into the Emacs face customization interface, where you can change the colors and save them.  This does not involve any extra packages or themes, and has been part of Emacs a long time (so you don't need to worry about which version you have).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! When I type `M-x customize-faces` and hit the TAB-button, Emacs changes it to `M-x customize-apropos-faces`. If I then press TAB again, it says `[Sole completion]`. Then I press the return-button, and it says `Search for faces (word list or regexp):`. Pressing return again gives a `Wrong type argument: stringp, nil`. Any idea?

Comment: Oops, I typed faces instead of face, and forgot a RET. Try now.

Comment: That was better. When I type `M-x customize-face`, hit RET, and then hit TAB, I get the list I think you're talking about. A plethora of completions. One of them, `font-lock-keyword-face`, I tried to customize with `(set-face-foreground 'font-lock-keyword-face "#36648b")`, and it works. But when I try the one called `org-todo`, it doesn't work. And org-mode is the reason I'm getting started with Emacs. I use version 24.3 btw. What could be the reason `(set-face-foreground 'org-todo "#000000")` doesn't work?

Comment: By "doesn't work", btw, I mean that Emacs responds on startup with: `error: Invalid face, org-todo`.

Comment: OK, it seems special ways are needed to define some of those faces. I managed to set `org-todo` and others with an expression like: `(setq org-todo-keyword-faces '(("TODO" . "#36648b") ("NEXT" . "#ffff00") ("WAITING" . "#36648b") ("SOMEDAY" . "#36648b") ("DONE!" . "#000000")))` which I read about on [orgmode.org/manual/Faces-for-TODO-keywords.html](http://orgmode.org/manual/Faces-for-TODO-keywords.html)